# Resending multiple emails simultaneously through Sent Items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Is there a plugin with which I can go to **Sent** Folder >> Select Multiple Mails >> And Resend them?

[image]

Currently What I have to do is open each mail >> Go to Other Actions >> Then resend it.

I have outlook 2003 on desktop and outlook 2007 on laptop both doesnt seem to have this feature, is it available in outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still following old method.